# Title caption missing for images in google images

Tags: wordpress, google-image-search

I have been posting blogs on my website recently. I tried searching the images for certain keywords on the google images section, the problem is that the image only shows the site title but the title of the page where the image added is missing.

Having just the site title makes no sense for the keyword we looked for. What am I doing  wrong or what do I need to change or add to have the title of that specific page below the image on google image section?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I hadn't called the title inside function.php and that's why the title of my blog pages wasn't visible in the google search engines. Refer the following link if anyone faced the same issue as me

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-page-title-not-showing/